# javascript class instances handling event inconsistently - this/scoping confusion

Tags: javascript, events, d3.js, scope, this

(Edited shortly after posting to simplify.)

The Title's not very specific, I apologize but I'm not sure what to ask more specifically.

Full jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/scottbrown0001/byz63qxm/6/

I'm confused as to why the code below produces the following behavior: the line

```
      d3.select(this).select('.here').text(name);
```

places the expected values "Foo 1" and "Foo 2" of `name` in each of two divs, but the line

```
      d3.select(this).select('.there').text(thisFoo.name);
```

always places the same instance's `name` in both divs.

It seems obvious it's a scoping issue or something, but I'm at a loss to understand why it behaves as it does.

```
  <style>
    div {margin: 20px; }
    .top {margin-top: 40px; }
    </style>

    </head>
<body>

  <div class='top top1'>
    <div class='clicker'>
      CLICK ME
      <div class='here'> HERE </div>
      <div class='there'> THERE </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  <div class='top top2'>
    <div class='clicker'>
      CLICK ME
      <div class='here'> HERE </div>
      <div class='there'> THERE </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

  <script>

    // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
    d3.selection.prototype.trigger = function(event, detail) {
      var e = new CustomEvent(event, detail);
      this.node().dispatchEvent(e);
      return this;
      }

    // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
    function Foo(where, name) {

      this.name = name;

      var top = d3.select('.' + where);
      var clicker = top.select('.clicker');

      thisFoo = this;

      clicker.on(
        'click',
        function(){
          d3.select(this).select('.here').text(name);
          d3.select(this).select('.there').text(thisFoo.name);
          }
        )

      }

  foo1 = new Foo('top1', 'Foo 1');
  foo2 = new Foo('top2', 'Foo 2');


    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you didn't use the `var` keyword when declaring `thisFoo`, you made it a global variable :

> Assigning a value to an undeclared variable implicitly creates it as a
>   global variable (it becomes a property of the global object) when the
>   assignment is executed.

So what is happening is that the line `foo1 = new Foo('top1', 'Foo 1');` is executed, after which `thisFoo` is a reference to the newly created `Foo` object. The following line `foo2 = new Foo('top2', 'Foo 2');` changes the value of the global variable `thisFoo` so that it becomes a reference to the second `Foo` object.

Your code should work the way you intend if you make sure to use the `var` keyword to make sure `thisFoo` is bound to `Foo`'s function scope.

Comment: Thanks Julien! Pretty simple, but I completely missed that!